# How to trace all client's actions in a session?

Tags: security

How to investigate and analyze possible ways to identify users of web surfing sessions and to investigate possible ways to track and identify actual individuals what they have done.
I want to get some info for this question briefly.
thanks guys.
i tried to use some of the elements with consideration such as
a) cookies
b)Authentication protocols
c) Tracking devices
d) server and proxy logs
e) Ipsec
f) eaves dropping
g) spoofing
h) TCP mapping
i) Scripting....etc...,

Comment: You want us, to help you violate people's privacy?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not clear what you are trying to achieve with tracking users behaviour. If you authenticate users, then you can use session id to identify users request. If you are not using authentication, then you can probably do similar thing by tracking user's IP address.

Comment: As Jacco mentioned, you should be careful here. You want to do it anonymously or with user's permission.

Comment: Hi Knoguchi, I was trying to trace a client and his browsed sessions. I want to trace his details and find out any sort of information. for example we can get some info by cookies and using some proxy logs. So for getting a proper information about the user who browsed the session, what all we can use to achieve the data??

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear what information about users you want. Probably, it helps me if you list up the concrete examples. In fact, the comment "I want to trace his details and find out any sort of information." is creepy. Assuming you want to trace a client behaviour like which page he visited and how long he stayed on each page for analysis purpose, you can associate user with his session id and you can track the request made by the user by associating it with the session id. So, at the server side you can log the requests with any attribute you want to keep track of.